# Github Actions Runner Cant Find R Packages

Tags: r, docker, github-actions

I'm a bit of a novice with Docker and Actions--looking for some help combining the two. I am trying to automate a workflow to pull data from an API. I have successfully built a docker image, but I am having a tough time getting things to work on the GitHub runner. The data gets requested using a private R package I created, which needs to be loaded onto the Github runner. My thought was to create a docker image with the R package and all the dependencies installed. I am able to launch the container locally and everything is there (R packages, code, etc.), but when I try to run the Github Action inside the container, the runner is unable to find the packages. As far as I can tell from the logs, the runner pulls the image and can run the container.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r2u

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libgit2-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libudunits2-dev \
    libgdal-dev \
    libgeos-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages('renv', repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cloud.r-project.org'))"

WORKDIR /rtipa

RUN mkdir -p renv

COPY renv.lock renv.lock
COPY .Rprofile .Rprofile
COPY renv/activate.R renv/activate.R
COPY renv/settings.json renv/settings.json
COPY builds/rtipa_0.0.1.tar.gz builds/rtipa_0.0.1.tar.gz

RUN mkdir renv/.cache

ENV RENV_PATHS_CACHE renv/.cache

RUN R -e "renv::restore()"
RUN R -e "renv::snapshot()"

RUN R -e "install.packages('builds/rtipa_0.0.1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"

CMD ["R", "--no-save"]
```

I expected my container to behave similar to [rocker images](https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker), which work fine. For example, when running the 'rocker/tidyverse' container, I am able to load tidyverse (`library(tidyverse)`) with no problem. When I try to load my R package, I receive an error that there is no R packages installed.

I've pulled the image on another machine (Mac), all the packages/directories are there when the container is running.

[Here is the log indicating the container is running:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fhC.png)

[Runner cant load package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKrhl.png)

Here is my actions YML file:

```
on:
 [push]

jobs:
  run_rtipa:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: wolfeclw/rtipa:amd64_v1.0.3

    steps:
      - name: intall_rtipa
        shell: Rscript {0}
        run: |
           install.packages('sessioninfo')
           sessioninfo::session_info()
           library(rtipa)
       
     # - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Comment: Rocker co-maintainer here.  `rocker/r-ver` may not be the best choice for this (as it has a different focus, this is documented).  You may want to look into [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) which we offer as `rocker/r2u`. I and many other use this happily at GitHub Actions (and it also underpins my [r-ci](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r-ci).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I updated the base image to be `rocker/r2u`, but I am still getting the same result.  Do you have an other recommendations? I updated my Dockerfile in original post.

Comment: I am not a user of `renv` or related overlays. I use `r2u` as it iis meant to be used via `install.packages()` (and/or via `apt`): it installs packages into `/isr/lib/R/site-package/` where they are found.

Comment: You are installing `rtpia` from source but do not specify where to (the `lib` argument). You install a number of other control files such as `Rprofile` that may goven this.  This is all under your control, and you need to straighten this out.  Maybe start with an empty Dockerfile that just tries to install `rtipa` (into its default location `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` where it will be found) and start from there.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel removing lines: `COPY renv/activate.R renv/activate.R`,
`COPY renv/settings.json renv/settings.json`, `COPY .Rprofile .Rprofile` from the Dockerfile worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it works.